# VS Code can't find Mono for OmniSharp

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense, omnisharp

## Edit

Fixed in OmniSharp update 1.25.2 [here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/tag/v1.25.2)

### TLDR;

VS Code says it requires Mono when it's already installed

### Goal

I am try to use VS Code with Unity and get intellisense to work in Code.

### Error

Here's the exact message I'm getting when I open my c# project in VS Code from Unity:

[image]

Also in Code's output I see this error message:

> OmniSharp failed to start because of missing requirements.

### Configurations and Confirmations

- I have confirmed I have Mono installed via `which mono` and `mono --version`
- I have also confirmed I have MSBuild installed via `dotnet msbuild`
- The c# extension is installed and `omnisharp.useModernNet` is set to `false`
- Unity External Script Editor is set to VS Code with the following checked: Embedded packages, Local packages, and Packages from unknown sources.

### Things I've Tried

- The mono path is slightly different than the default, so I tried adding the path to VS Code with no change.
- I typed `mono --version` in the VS Code terminal and got the version as expected
- Deleting the "Assembly-CSharp.csproj" and the ".sln" files, then in Unity regenerating the project files.
- Turning it off and on again (aka restarting my computer and the programs).
- If I set `omnisharp.useModernNet` to `true` then I get the following error in VS Codes output:

> This project targets .NET version that requires reference assemblies that are not installed (e.g. .NET Framework). The most common solution is to make sure Mono is fully updated on your machine (https://mono-project.com/download/) and that you are running the .NET Framework build of OmniSharp (e.g. 'omnisharp.useModernNet': false in C# Extension for VS Code).

### System and Versions

- macOS 12.6.1
- Mac mini M1 2020
- VSCode 1.73.0
- Unity 2021.3.13f1
- dotnet 7.0.100
- mono 6.12.0.182
- MSBuild version 17.4.0+18d5aef85 for .NET

Answer (score 4):

it's a known **Omnisharp** (**1.25.1**) [issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5443). I think you'll either have to wait for a patch release or downgrade your **Omnisharp** back to version **1.25.0**.

Comment: Awesome, so I'm not crazy! I'll keep an eye on the update progress. Thanks Hamid.

Comment: GW.Rodriguez you're welcome!

Comment: Looks like it's going to be in the next update 1.25.2: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/tag/v1.25.2

Comment: Just got the 1.25.2 update and it's all fixed.

Comment: I also can confirm the 1.25.2 patch fixed the issue.